# Wordpress Email Issue

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

I am having a problem with wordpress woocommerce. I installed woocommerce and configured out everything. But Woocommerce do no sent order e-mail to customer. Then I searched problem and I decided to setup POSTMAN SMTP plugin. But it does not work too. How can I overcome ?

[Postman Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rqb9T.png)

[Wocommerce settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzgSZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a plugin for something you can't directally see breaking. Anyway no need. If you go to your admin Panel, - e-commerce settings - then select email tab - processing order (in secondary menu) and enable email notification. I hope this helps.